# How does a migration discover the database type in Fluent Migrator?

Tags: fluent-migrator

Using Fluent Migrator, how does a Migration class method discover the nature of the database being migrated?   I need to know whether it is SQLite or something else.

I know there is a legacy class called MigratorDotNetMigration but I do not want to give up the power of Fluent Migrator--and this is not a legacy migration I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Dealing-with-Multiple-Database-Types).  It is based on IsDatabase().